# Django prevent creating objects in concurrency

Tags: django, concurrency

models:

```
class CouponUsage(models.Model):
    coupon = models.ForeignKey('Coupon', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="usage")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    

class Coupon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    capacity = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def remaining(self):
        usage = self.usage.all().count()
        return self.capacity - usage
```

views:

```
def use_coupon(request):
    coupon = Coupon.objects.get(condition)

    if coupon.remaining > 0:
        # do something
```

I don't know how to handle concurrency issues in the code above, I believe one possible bug is that when the if clause in the view is executing another CouponUsage object can be created...
how do I go about handling that?

how do I prevent CouponUsage objects from being created when inside the if clause in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to rely on the database integrity checks and transactions. Assuming your capacity must always be in the range [0, +infinity) you could change your `Coupon` model to use a `PositiveIntegerField` instead of an `IntegerField`:

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Then you need to update your `Coupon` capacity every time a `CouponUsage` is created. You can override the `save()` method to reflect this change:

```
from django.db import models, transaction

class CouponUsage(models.Model):
    coupon = models.ForeignKey('Coupon', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="usage")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

    @transaction.atomic()
    def save(self, ...):  # Arguments missing
        if not self.pk:  # This is an insert, you may want to raise an error otherwise
            self.coupon.capacity = models.F('capacity') - 1  # The magic is here, this is executed at the database level so no problem with old in memory values
            self.coupon.save()
        super().save(...)
```

Now whenever a `CuponUsage` is created you update the capacity for the associated `Coupon` instance. The key here is that instead of reading the value from database into python's memory, updating and then saving, which could lead to inconsistent results, the update to `capacity` is made at the database level using [an F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions). This guarantees that no two transactions use the same value.

Now, notice that by using a `PositiveInteger` field instead of an `IntegerField` the database will also guarantee that `capacity` cannot fall below 0. Therefore if you now try to create a `CuponUsage` instance such that the `Cupon` capacity would get a negative value, an exception will arise, thus preventing the creation of such `CuponUsage`.

You now need to take advantage of this in your code by doing something like the following:

```
def use_coupon(request):
    coupon = Coupon.objects.get(condition)

    try:
        usage = CuponUsage.objects.create(coupon=coupon)
        # Do whatever you want here, you already 'consumed' a coupon
    except IntegrityError:  # Check for the specific exception
        # Sorry no capacity left
        pass
```

If in the event of getting the coupon you need to do things that may fail, and in such a case you need to 'revert' the usage, you can enclose your whole `use_coupon` function inside a transaction.